# How to turn led ON when pushing the boot button on an esp32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm trying to turn the LED (pin 2) ON when I push the boot button on an esp32 ! Here is my code ! Any idea why this don't work ?

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 0;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  2;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is fatally flawed in multiple ways, primarily, while the chip is booting the i/o pins are not under your code's control, as soon as that signal is detected your program stops running. Rebooting restores their default power-up states.  Plus that button input is surely serviced by an interrupt, your polling loop will never see it go high, ever.

If you want an LED that stays on while the chip is booting you'll need another component, like a JFET.  Connect an i/o pin to the JFET's gate, and its source and drain pins in series with either the power or ground leg of the LED, then set that i/o pin high while your program is running, to bias the JFET, thus keeping an open circuit between source and drain.  As soon as the gate goes low, the circuit closes and your LED turns on.  When the bootstrap executes your program, it sets that pin high again, LED goes off.  And as a bonus you won't need to waste any compute polling an i/o.  Win:win!